# Application name in Windows 10's timeline - WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

I have the following code:

```
UserActivitySession _currentActivity;
private async Task GenerateActivityAsync()
{
   // Get the default UserActivityChannel and query it for our UserActivity. If the activity doesn't exist, one is created.
    UserActivityChannel channel = UserActivityChannel.GetDefault();
    UserActivity userActivity = await channel.GetOrCreateUserActivityAsync("Test");

    // Populate required properties
    userActivity.VisualElements.DisplayText = ActivityName.Text; //ActivityName is textbox
    userActivity.ActivationUri = new Uri(ActivityUri.Text); //ActivityUri is also textbox
    userActivity.VisualElements.Description = "This is test item";
    userActivity.VisualElements.Attribution =
        new UserActivityAttribution(new Uri("http://via.placeholder.com/16x16"))
        { AlternateText = "Test123" };

    //Save
    await userActivity.SaveAsync(); //save the new metadata

    // Dispose of any current UserActivitySession, and create a new one.
    _currentActivity?.Dispose();
    _currentActivity = userActivity.CreateSession();
}
```

And it results in something like on the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MfYH.jpg

I want my app's name to be displayed after the dash character (the dash is inserted there by Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You code specifies this:

```
userActivity.VisualElements.DisplayText = ActivityName.Text;
```

tried changing the DisplayText to the value you want?
Getting app name:

```
var pack = Package.Current.Id.Name;
```

Comment: 1. DisplayText is rendered inside card, not above, after the dash
2. Package.Current throws an exception in WinForms
3. ActivityName is textbox